# Show Posts via cat+cat in URL that are in both Categories doesn’t work

Tags: categories, query, search, tags

it seems like i am the only person on this planet currently experiencing this issue. When i search for [www.gooloo.de/category/balea+vegan](http://www.gooloo.de/category/balea+vegan), it should only show posts, that are in BOTH categories, but it only acknowledges the first category tag.

A Developer said:
Confirmed. SQL contains a 0=1 clause when category name contains a '+'.
I thought a workaround would be to use "pre_get_posts" action to intercept "category_name" query vars containing a '+' and compose a "tax_query" arg instead using 'operator => 'AND', . Same result, the SQL ends up with a 0=1 clause.

I have submitted this issue now to Fixing WordPress and Core but no one seems to care. So i am asking: has anybody an Idea how to fix this issue? I've build on this mechanism for years now and no, i don't want to purchase another plugin and fix thousands of links containing this structure.

For Reference, my Tickets: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/55426 | https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-posts-that-are-in-both-categories-doesnt-work/#new-topic-0

I have received the following info, but since i just started using WordPress a couple months ago (moved from Blogger) and never ever tried working with PHP and such (i know basic HTML and CSS), i was asking if someone has an idea how to make this work?:

The docs offer several ways of doing a category intersection.

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__and' => array( 2, 6 ) )); One of the methods mentioned on that page (unsure 100% whether it does an intersection because I haven't tested it) is a slug+slug format, which loosely implies it does an intersection, but in any case it looks familiar to your use case.

Here is my functions.php: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_XFN1jsd--B7hppQGtVAhUKcVEAEkimr/view?usp=sharing
And here are the Snippets i use in functions.php through the Code Snippets Plugin:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MKYLj2_821t-wNFI7MR7OPFMlkrEmCUc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is this WordPress v6.0? Have you tried switching to a default/core theme like 2021, and did the same issue persist - i.e. after switching theme, try visiting `www.gooloo.de/category/balea+vegan` and see if it works as expected. If not, then you can try deactivating plugins and if the issue is gone, then one of those plugins is causing the issue.

Comment: @SallyCJ I tried both. Issue persists. I even ran completely in safe mode and the issue still persists. Divi, the Themecreator, also has no known issue like that. Yes, i'm running on 6.0 with the latest update.

Comment: Can you recall when did the issue started to happen? Have you checked your `.htaccess` file - what's the code in there? Have you tried reinstalling WordPress core files via wp-admin → Dashboard → Updates? And I doubt this would help, but you can try clearing your caches (server/site and browser).

Comment: Hey @SallyCJ the .htaccess looks absolutely fine. I couldn't see anything worth noting. The Issue startet a long time ago, i have been sent from forum to forum, from one WordPress Group to another. So i think maybe a year ago or so. Cache is cleared daily, so nothing to do here. And yes, i've tried reinstalling WP. With 5.8, 5.9 and 6.0

Comment: Reddit? How dare you.

Comment: @vancoder Yep, made the same mistake twice. But as you don't have anything to contribute, why leave a comment?

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ, no i was not able to get it to work. I had to buy GridBuilder to make up for it, but the query is still broken.

Comment: I'm not able to help you with that plugin, but instead of trying to make the default `/category` URL works with the `cat+cat`, you could actually add custom rewrite rules like `/categories/cat+cat`, so have you considered that?

Comment: @SallyCJ No i haven't, what do you mean by that? Because if the query doesn't work, why would a redirect work then? :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I was looking at or maybe thinking of something else when I said the `cat+cat` was never supported, so basically, I deleted that comment. And are you actually completely certain `cat+cat` really didn't work? Try installing [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) and visit any valid `/category/<slug>+<slug>` page (i.e. there are posts in the specified categories), then open Query Monitor via the *admin bar* and check if you're seeing something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olNuo.png)? You can also share the entire SQL query.

Comment: @SallyCJ Sorry, can't do that. Query Monitor doesn't work, doesn't show up; the Admin Bar doesn't work and after activating the entire Website crashes.

Comment: @SallyCJ I've now asked my Hoster if he can get that Info and get Query Monitor to work properly; will update you ASAP.

Comment: @SallyCJ Here is the Monitor Results: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YZhBTrWRbbZrA6O1wKjdmPOr-yBP3iIj?usp=sharing | My Hoster said the following: "Regarding the query monitor, on my end this is working as expected - however the query list is not updating with anything even after refreshing that page. Please see the attached screenshots of what is shown for that entire tab."

Comment: @SallyCJ And here is the exact Query Monitor Output on https://www.gooloo.de/category/balea+vegan in PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WKI-M_gZlsJDH4w0ilKZSPzAWKxnDdE1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So I could see the main query did query only the posts in both the `balea` and `vegan` categories, see page 1 in that PDF and look at the [3rd column which contained "Main Query"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCkaA.png), and thus, please try again with this: 1. Switch to the *unmodified* 2021 theme; 2. Deactivate ALL plugins; 3. Clear your site caches if any; and share the new Query Monitor output and a screenshot of [that page](https://www.gooloo.de/category/balea+vegan).

Comment: Well I mean, all plugins except Query Monitor..

Comment: @SallyCJ I can't do that in Health Check. I'm unable to activate Query Monitor.

Comment: @SallyCJ Sorry, that was my mistake. Had to activate it once before using Site Health. Here is the Query: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tYe5CJZ1RuugLLMqTicLYFY1tQTcFfJU/view?usp=sharing and here is the Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wtWUqK-zcRBA7FPVkE6qHYUvVXpIidcc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So some of those posts did belong in the `balea` **and** `vegan` categories (i.e. the posts were assigned to both categories), but some other posts only belong in one of that categories, right? And if so, then now that all other plugins were deactivated and yet the issue still persisted, I suggest you to hire someone to identify what's really going on and try to fix it.

Comment: Or (before doing that), you can try [this tiny plugin](https://gist.github.com/5ally/4069cfd7a76de04224f9b7e8b2dcd8ba?permalink_comment_id=4246075#gistcomment-4246075) and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ I replied on your Git :)